# Find a vector with a particular linear transformation given the matrix of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Φ : R4 → R3 be the linear transformation with the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 3& 2 \\
        1 & 1 & 4 &1\\
        1 & -1 & 0 &1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
Find a vector **v** in R
4
such that Φ(**v**) = [1, 0, 0].

My problem here, is I'm not quite sure to handle this type of problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a transformation $f$ with the matrix $A$, then for a vector $V$ of the right dimension you have $f(V)=AV$

For instance if the matrix of $f$ is $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 3 \\
        1 & 1 & 4\\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $f(V)=\begin{bmatrix}
        3\\1
        \end{bmatrix}$ : let $V=\begin{bmatrix}
        a\\b\\c
        \end{bmatrix}$ then

$AV=\begin{bmatrix}
        2a+3c\\a+b+4c
        \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        3\\1
        \end{bmatrix}$

Then you solve it for $a,b,c$ and that gives you the set of suitable $V$s.

With that, you can solve your problem :-)